# T-SQL XML Query, how to seperate matching nodes into individual rows?

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath

I have a table that has a column full of XML like:

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <name>Sally</name>
   </child>
   <child>
      <name>Bobby</name>
   </child>
</parent>
```

I'm trying to extract all of the names of the children into seperate rows. My desired resultset would look like:

```
   Sally
   Bobby
```

However, if I do something like:

```
SELECT data.query('data(//parents/child/name)') FROM stuff
```

I get back a single row that looks like

```
Sally Bobby
```

What am I doing wrong with the XPath?

EDIT: Not the real schema or data, just an example. Also, I can't simply split on spaces.

Comment: Note, I found your question via: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53911/a-more-interesting-user-specific-unanswered-feed so don't forget to vote it up :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look into `CROSS APPLY`:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-cross-apply-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
create table #t (data xml)


insert #t values ('
<parent>
   <child>
      <name>Sally</name>
   </child>
   <child>
      <name>Bobby</name>
   </child>
</parent>
')


insert #t values ('
<parent>
   <child>
      <name>Fred</name>
   </child>
   <child>
      <name>Bill</name>
   </child>
</parent>
')


select C.* from #t 
cross apply 
 (select name.value('name[1]', 'varchar(255)') as [Name] 
    from data.nodes('//parent/child') as c(name)) as C
```

​