# T-SQL XML Query, how to separate matching nodes into individual rows? Part II

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

This question follows up this great answer: [T-SQL XML Query, how to seperate matching nodes into individual rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596904/t-sql-xml-query-how-to-seperate-matching-nodes-into-individual-rows/10451753#10451753)
What if the values where:

```
   <child>
    <name>Fred</name>
    <sname>Flintstone</name>
   </child>
   <child>
    <name>Bill</name>
    <sname>Gates</name>
   </child>
```

And I wanted the output to be like:

```
Fred
Flintstone
Bill
Gates
```

Or even better, this:

```
name: Fred
sname: Flintstone
name: Bill
sname: Gates
```

(all in one column)

-->Since I can't answer my own question for the next 3 hours, I'll edit my question as suggested by stackoverflow. Here's my answer to my own question:

I've figured it out! :-) So I'm obliged to share my own solution. Here it is:

```
SELECT
  distinct childs.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') + '=' + childs.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Children
FROM  
  #t CROSS APPLY
  data.nodes('//parent/child/*') AS Children(childs)
```

Thanks anyone for having a look at my question!

Comment: Your question was not clear. marc_s's solution will produce desired output. Also, the last answer, Mikael Eriksson's answer is published 12m before you edited your question (by adding your solution). I think you should choose one of these answers as a solution for your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @XML xml
set @XML = 
'<child>
  <name>Fred</name>
  <sname>Flintstone</sname>
 </child>
 <child>
   <name>Bill</name>
   <sname>Gates</sname>
 </child>'

select N.value('concat(local-name(.),": ",.)', 'varchar(max)')
from @XML.nodes('/child/*') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
name: Fred 
sname: Flintstone 
name: Bill 
sname: Gates
```

**Update:**
Using a table and a guaranteed `order by`

```
declare @XML xml
set @XML = 
'<child>
  <name>Fred</name>
  <sname>Flintstone</sname>
 </child>
 <child>
   <name>Bill</name>
   <sname>Gates</sname>
 </child>'

declare @T table (ID int identity primary key, XMLColumn xml)
insert into @T values(@XML)
insert into @T values(@XML)

select ID,
       Names
from
  (
    select ID,
           N.value('concat(local-name(.),": ",.)', 'varchar(max)') as Names,
           row_number() over(partition by ID order by T.N) as rn
    from @T
      cross apply XMLColumn.nodes('/child/*') as T(N)
  ) T
order by ID, rn
```

Comment: Concerning the order of the result, this is even better. Thanks Mikael!

Comment: @stakes Without a `order by` the order of the rows is arbitrary. There is no guarantee that the order will always be what you see not. What order do you want? There is a trick if you want to the order the nodes appear in the XML.

Comment: I want the order to be like you posted, the order of the nodes indeed. I'm very curious about the trick, what is it?

Comment: @stakes - It is in the update I posted. Using `row_number()` over the shredded XML column `T.N`. Read more about it [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/03/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense-rank.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the two-columns per `<child>` output :

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<child>
    <name>Fred</name>
    <sname>Flintstone</sname>
   </child>
   <child>
    <name>Bill</name>
    <sname>Gates</sname>
   </child>'

SELECT
    'name: ' + child.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    'sname: ' + child.value('(sname)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @input.nodes('/child') AS nodes(child)
```

Output is:

```
name: Fred  |  sname: Flintstone
name: Bill  |  sname: Gates
```

If you want just one column, you can use this instead:

```
SELECT
    'name: ' + child.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @input.nodes('/child') AS nodes(child)

UNION

SELECT
    'sname: ' + child.value('(sname)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @input.nodes('/child') AS nodes(child)
```

and this gives you this output:

```
(No column name)
name: Bill
name: Fred
sname: Flintstone
sname: Gates
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. It is still not exactly what I want, but in the mean time I already figured it out. See my own answer... :-S